# Can I BCC an email through SharePoint Designer workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, email, workflow

The standard SharePoint 'Send Email' workflow activity does not support a BCC field, however I need to send an email BCC'd to a SharePoint group.

I am prepared to write a custom workflow in VS 2008 to deliver this, however I thought I would ask the question here in case there is a quicker method to deliver this type of functonality.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can actually do this in SPD 2010, but not from the Define Email Message dialog box. Set up everything except the BCC and click Ok.  With the email step highlighted, in the Workflow ribbon click the Advanced Properties button.  The ONLY other "advanced" property this exposes is...the BCC field.  Not sure why they don't just have this in the dialog...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear to like it if I only provide the BCC field. Won't publish without a *To:* recipient.

Comment: @DavidClarke, I got around this by sending it To to same administrative address I was sending From. (Or some other system address.)  You can then filter these out with a mail rule if you don't want to get them.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to BCC the email?

Could you not just have two 'Send Email' workflow activities that sends the email to each recipent?

:)

Comment: The receipients are in a group.  I do not want to have to manage the workflow seperately from the group membership.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a code example (No Visual Studio Required) of how to specify BCCs as well as the From Address and optional email attachments from a SharePoint Designer Workflow.

[Send rich emails with attachments from a SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/send-rich-emails-with-attachments-from.html).

Note that this uses the Workflow Power Pack for SharePoint. I think it is fantastic, but then I worked on it so I may be a bit biased ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the *Advanced Properties* button and add a BCC.

check this link for further illustration:
https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/add-a-bcc-recipient-to-a-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow/